# Is it safe if one accidentally swallowed a piece of the foam that is between the hard drive and the electronics

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I know this isn't normal, but it is important. In a laptop hard drive, there is a foam between the electronics and the actual drive. I was wondering what this was and if it was toxic as I swallowed some by accident.

Comment: Actually, your question is mostly a "health" question rather than a computer question, so it's pushing the boundaries of being on-topic here (we're not really experts on the health implications).  I wouldn't be surprised if this gets closed, especially if it attracts a bunch of wise-ass answers and comments (in all honesty, I might VTC it myself based on the subject matter), but at least you got some reasonable feedback that, hopefully, will ease your mind.

Comment: @JakeGould I would say that eating a screw is safer as it is less likely to be absorbed by the stomach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're supposed to eat just the hard drive, not the foam.  :-)

It is likely there to cushion the drive to lessen the bumps from handling the laptop.  It may also help to keep thinner drives from moving around.

The foam, itself is inert, although who knows what kinds of contaminants might be on it.  The foam and any contaminants inside the laptop would be stuff you might handle and could get on your hands, so none of it should be seriously toxic in small amounts (otherwise the government wouldn't allow its use in a consumer device).  It probably isn't good for you, so you wouldn't want to make it a regular part of your diet, but a small piece shouldn't hurt you.

From the time you swallow it, it takes about eight hours to get to your large intestine and about another 40 hours to be eliminated.  So if you get any unusual symptoms within a few days of swallowing it, check with a doctor.  If you're symptom-free for a few days after that, you can stop waiting for the other shoe to drop.

Disclaimer: this is just "informed opinion".  I'm not a doctor and don't even play one on TV.  So if you have serious concerns, check with your doctor, even if just for your own peace of mind.